# IIS - Start In Directory

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, iis-6

I am setting up a new test server for an application created by a previous developer.  Please see the code below:

```
strLines = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
    lngLinesRead = UBound(strLines)
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open "log.txt"For Append As #intFile
    Print #intFile, Now & " ***************** Start of import. User: " & strUser & " on: " & strTerminal & " ******************** "
    Close #intFile
```

This code is creating a log file in the following location: "c:\windows\syswow64\isvr\log.txt.  On the live server (and existing test server) it is written to: c:\iispages\app\log.txt.  How do you specify the relative path? Is this done in IIS.

When creating a scheduled task; there is a 'start in' option where you can specify the starting directory.  Is there something similar in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

The file is going to be written into the "current folder" of the web server.  This will be the folder where the ASP page is executed from.  The two paths you posted represent the active folders the different web servers were using when those files were written. You can specify a deeper path in the Open statement:

Open "c:\windows\syswow64\isvr\SUBFOLDER\SUBFOLDER\log.txtFor Append As #intFile

But since this is being managed by IIS, it must be a folder that IIS service is allowed to write to.  If you need to write to a folder outside the scope of the web service you can edit the folder permissions in windows to give permission.

Comment: Where do you specify the location of the folder? It is not specified in the application.

Comment: The current folder will be the folder in which your running ASP page resides.  In IIS you can create a virtual directory in the website folder that leads to anywhere on the drive if that will help.
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/8c110149-8060-4dd7-9bdb-e262c21483dd.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: You could create virtual directories on both servers name LOGS.  Then your open statement would be identical on both severs:
Open "LOGS\log.txt"For Append As #intFile even though the virtual folders will lead to different places on each physical drive.